# Haskell - x not in scope when declaring set

Tags: haskell, set, element

I'm trying to create a set of 1 integer. Now this integer must be divisible by 7, but must give a remainder of 1 when divided by 6,5,4,3 or 2. 
So I created 6 sets, where x must be the first element that is an element of all of those sets. 
Why do I get an out of bounds error?

```
a = [(2*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
b = [(3*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
c = [(4*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
d = [(5*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
e = [(6*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
f = [7*x | x<-[1..]]

z = [x | x<-[1], x elem a]


main = print(z)
```

error message:

```
/Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:1:27:
    No instance for (Enum t0)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘1 .. ’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      a :: [t0]
        (bound at /Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:1:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Enum Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Enum Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 7 others
    In the expression: [1 .. ]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1 .. ]
    In the expression: [(2 * x) + 1 | x <- [1 .. ]]

/Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:1:28:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal ‘1’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      a :: [t0]
        (bound at /Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:1:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [1 .. ]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1 .. ]

/Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:8:22:
    No instance for (Num ((a0 -> [a0] -> Bool) -> [t0] -> Bool))
      arising from the literal ‘1’
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [1]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1]

/Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:8:28:
    No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘elem’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: (a0 -> [a0] -> Bool) -> [t0] -> Bool
        (bound at /Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:8:18)
      z :: [(a0 -> [a0] -> Bool) -> [t0] -> Bool]
        (bound at /Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Eq a => Eq (Control.Applicative.ZipList a)
        -- Defined in ‘Control.Applicative’
      instance Eq Integer -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type’
      ...plus 23 others
    In the first argument of ‘x’, namely ‘elem’
    In the expression: x elem a
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x elem a

/Users/Dennis/Google Drive/Programming/Haskell/eggs.hs:11:16:
    No instance for (Show ((a0 -> [a0] -> Bool) -> [t0] -> Bool))
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In the expression: print (z)
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (z)
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: First of all `2x` isn't valid. You probably meant `2*x`. Also, list comprehensions are `[x | x <- [...], elem x a, elem x b, ...]`.

Comment: Sorry, I had put in the *, only left it out when writing the code here, my bad

Comment: Still getting error, updated code

Comment: Can you post the actual error message you're getting?  From what I can tell your `z` would evaluate to bottom (`undefined`) because you're trying to check if `1` is an element of `[3,5,7..]` and it's trying to check if a `1` appears anywhere in that list, which happens to be infinite.

Comment: There's the error message. Thanks for your time

Comment: Like _almost always_ in Haskell, the errors become a lot less strange when you add type signatures.

Comment: I get errors on type signatures

Comment: Couldnt match expected type

Comment: @JohnDoe What type signatures did you add?  What type couldn't be matched?  These details are more important to the problem than the statement "Couldn't match expected type".  Always be precise when specifying what the problem is.

Comment: The snippet `z = [x | x<-[1], x elem a]` looks wrong. First you need backticks around ``elem``. Then, if 1 belongs to `a` it defines z as `[1]`, otherwise z is bound to `[]`. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Zeta commented, you have an issue in writing `x elem a`. That tells Haskell `x` is a function, and causes strange (type) errors. I think you meant `elem x a` or

```
x `elem` a
```

The following can be loaded in the GHCi -7.8 without a problem:

```
a = [(2*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
b = [(3*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
c = [(4*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
d = [(5*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
e = [(6*x)+1 | x<-[1..]]
f = [7*x | x<-[1..]]

z = [x | x<-[1], elem x a]

main = print z
```

The above fixes the syntax issue.

Now

> to create a set of 1 integer. Now this integer must be divisible by
>   7, but must give a remainder of 1 when divided by 6,5,4,3 or 2

I assume you want one (or the first) integer that satisfy all above properties.

In that case you need to use `take 1` or `head`, instead of `x <- [1]`

`x <- [1]` basically tells Haskell that 1 is the only choice in generating the list. Now why does it run forever?

```
 elem 1 a == elem 1 [(2*x)+1 | x <- [1..]] == elem 1 [3, 5 ..]
```

since `1` is not in the infinite list [3, 5 ..], and Haskell can never find out that `1` is not in a list until it scans all the elements, `elem x a` will take forever to evaluate.

One way to solve the problem is to use a decidable function like `mod` to tell, e.g. if mod x 2 == 1 or not, rather than testing set membership on an infinite list:

```
 z' = take 1 [ x | x <-f, mod x 6 == 1, mod x 5 == 1, mod x 4 == 1, mod x 3 == 1, mod x 2 == 1]
```

Now evaluating `z'` gives you:

```
*Main> z'
[301]
```

And

```
*Main> take 2 [ x | x <-f, mod x 6 == 1, mod x 5 == 1, mod x 4 == 1, mod x 3 == 1, mod x 2 == 1]
[301,721]
```

Comment: @JohnDoe probably meant to write ```z = [x | x <- [1], x `elem` a]``` instead, which would also work because it's equivalent to using `elem` in the prefix form as you've shown here.

Comment: Yes. I agree. Don't know how to write show a ` in SO.., so picked the other form. Just updated.

Comment: When writing a post, you can use the back tick inside code blocks without any problems, but in comments if you need to use a back tick in the code, you can use three as the delimiter instead, much like Python's multi-line string syntax with `'''a multi-\nline string'''` or similarly with double quotes.  So if you surround the code snippet with 3 back ticks on each side instead of just 1 then you can use back ticks within the snippet.

Comment: '''Thanks\n `a` lot:)'''

Comment: The program runs forever :/ Why doesn't it print my expected result ?